# How to install plugins for gedit on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, gedit, r

gedit in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394068/recommended-ide-for-r-under-linux/3395363#3395363) pretty much raised my interest as a light weight editor / IDE for R. 
I was happy to see that there is a .dmg for Mac OS X, but I still wonder where / how to install plugins, in particular this [one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rgedit/).

Is it even possible?

Comment: Gedit on OSX, seriously?! Have you checked out TextMate or SubEthaEdit?

Comment: I have TextWrangler for the light weight stuff and Eclipse for everything else. Also like Aptana Studio. The reason why I looked at gedit for Mac OS was that it was recommended by some SOers for use with R.

Comment: Ditto on TextMate, which has good integration with R. But you may also consider emacs/ess (or Vim with Vim-r-plugin2), which can follow you to every platform and have a huge support base.

Comment: @Nils Some people don't think you should have to _pay_ for a text editor.

Comment: @Jeff Some people don't think a programmer should be *paid* for his work.

Comment: @Tobia ...so you're agreeing with me? I don't get it.

Comment: @Jeff No, I don't agree, I was being ironic. So you really don't think people should be paid for their hard work.

Comment: @Tobia I don't know where you got that idea. I have no problem with TextMate or developers who charge for their products. My reply was in response to Nil's snarky comment that made no attempt to answer the question. You might as well respond to every question on AskDifferent with "seriously?! buy a PC!"... It's not helpful and not what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install gedit using [macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gedit) (which builds everything from source), or using [fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=gedit) (with pre-built binaries). I don't use gedit much, but I suppose that if the add-on you want comes as a source-code tarball, then one of these options may be more easily extendable/configurable than if gedit is installed with a .dmg.

Comment: So.. it doesn't work with the .dmg? Probably will stay with Komodo / Sciviews-K then. I was looking for easy to configure light weight stuff as an Eclipse / StatET alternative.

Comment: Note that the macports version is VERY old. You can get Gedit3 as a .dmg that doesn't have this plugin issue amymore... just install like you would on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do this too without much luck.  I have got a bit further though.  The error message when trying to load the R integration is as follows

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gedit-2/plugins/RCtrl.py", line 49, in <module>
    import vte
ImportError: No module named vte

** (gedit-bin:11508): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'R integration'
```

So it looks like you need to install the python vte library on OS X somehow but I couldn't work that out.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts seems to support it:

```
$ port search gedit
gedit @2.26.3 (gnome, editors)
    GNOME editor.

gedit-plugins @2.26.3 (gnome, editors)
    Plug-ins for GEdit
```

Answer (score 0):

To install Gedit plugins, you need to go into the gedit.app package:

1. Right click your Gedit app icon and select 'Show Package Contents'
2. Navigate to Contents/Resources/lib/gedit-2/plugins
3. Drop your plugins into that directory
4. Restart gedit and activate them normally (Preferences > Plugins)

FWIW, Gedit has some advantages (and few drawbacks) over TextMate. I'm switching over today for split panes (available through a plugin).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with any plugins I have tried. They all crash with a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Just like on Linux, you can put it into ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins (where ~ is your home directory).

Here are the commands that installed the AutoTab plugin which immediately after appeared in the Plugins section of Preferences:

```
mkdir -p ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins
cp autotab.gedit-plugin  autotab.py ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins
```

Comment: Does it run? Can you check the box next to AutoTab in Preferences without it crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is no longer an issue for Gedit 3 on Mountain Lion. Just install them exactly as you ordinarily would on a Linux distro.